# My socket client only seems to receive the first response from a HTTP server. Why?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to develop a class that allows me to run a socket on a thread, and that at any time allows me to send through it data, as well as receive a notifications when data arrives. It should assume no things such as only receiving a message after it has sent a message first, etc. 
By some reason, the following code is printing the response for only the first request:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    TCPClient client = new TCPClient(new TCPClientObserver());
    client.connect("www.microsoft.com", 80);

    sleep(1000);
    client.send("HTTP GET");

    sleep(5000);
    client.send("XYZ");
}
```

printing

```
echo: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
echo: <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
echo: <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
echo: <BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
echo: <hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
echo: </BODY></HTML>
```

Here is the core logic of the socket:

```
        echoSocket = new Socket("www.microsoft.com", 80);
        out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                echoSocket.getInputStream()));

        while (true) {
            String response = in.readLine();
            if (response != null)
                System.out.println("echo: " + response);
        }
```

I guess the problem lies in my loop?

The full test code of my app can be seen here:
http://codepad.org/bmHwct35

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the HTTP 400 is what you expected, you need to break out of your loop if readLine() returns null. This is usually written like this:

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the loop, but rather the first request you send. "HTTP GET" is invalid request and the server should respond with "400 Bad request", then close the connection. That's why you don't get response for your second message. Try a valid HTTP request e.g. "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.microsoft.com\r\n\r\n" instead. HTTP 1.1 connections are keep-alive by default, so you'll be able to send several of them and receive subsequent responses.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that HTTP servers talk the HTTP protocol, and your client code is not talking the protocol properly.  Instead it is opening a plain socket and writing random stuff that seems to be based on guesswork.

The HTTP protocol is specified in [this document](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).  If you read it, you will see that what you are doing is nothing like what a client is supposed to do.

I recommend that you don't attempt to implement your client this way.  Implementing the client side of the HTTP protocol from scratch is too much work ... and the world does not need yet another flakey HTTP client.  Either use the standard URL / HttpURLConnection APIs, or use a 3rd-party HTTP client library.

---

In your case, the 400 response is most likely a consequence of sending a malformed request.  An HTTP GET request (indeed any HTTP request) is supposed to include the target URL in the first line.  Read the spec.

Answer (score 1):

The first you send is an invalid request and after replying the server will close the connection. In your code you are then stuck in the `while (true)` loop as you will keep getting `null` back from `readLine` as the connection/stream is closed (end of stream reached).

```
while (true) { // <-- never terminates
  String response = in.readLine();
  if (response != null) // <- now null all the time
    System.out.println("echo: " + response);
}
```